# Issue using Knockout and checkboxes to make ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm developing an interface witch is a searcher, so it has filters, but this filters are made with an ajax call named Filter in each element the user selects. I'm using knockout to populate the values with a default search, but for some reason from the server comes an array kike this `rating: [5,4,3,2]` and other arrays with a different desgin like `categories:[{id:2, name:"PC components", count: 50}]`.
Issue 1: when I make click on one of the elements populated  from the rating array into the page, using:

```
    <!-- ko foreach: rating -->
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedRatings, click: $root.Filter " />
                    <span data-bind="text: $data + ' Stars'"></span>
                </label>
                <!-- /ko -->

it make the call but the checkbox is not checked, this is checked when i check some other. I try a many kind of things but nothing solve the problem.

Issue 2: When I check some of the checkboxes, the make the ajax call, but they show as checked when the action finish, no in the first selection. Why is that.

Here is my code:

    //observable
    function Searcher(){
    self = this;
            self.types = ko.observableArray();
            self.selectedTypes = ko.observableArray();

            self.rating = ko.observableArray();
            self.selectedRatings = ko.observableArray([]);


        //Rating
        self.noneRating = ko.observable(true);

        this.selectedRatings.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            self.noneRating(newValue && newValue.length == 0 ? true : false);
        }, self);

        self.noneRating.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                self.selectedRatings.removeAll();
                self.Filter();
            }
        });

        //Styles
        self.noneStyle = ko.observable(true);

        this.selectedStyles.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            self.noneStyle(newValue && newValue.length == 0 ? true : false);
        }, self);

        self.noneStyle.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                self.selectedStyles.removeAll();
                self.Filter();
            }
        });

     self.getSearchFilters = function () {
                debugger;
                var json = ko.toJSON({ type: self.selectedTypes(), rating: self.selectedRatings()});
                return json;
            };

     self.Filter = function () {
                self.filterbuttonActive(false);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url/Find",
                    data: "{ 'search':'" + + "', 'filter': '" + self.getFilters() + "' }",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        //something here
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                       //something here to load data
                    },
                    error: function (a, desc, error) {
                       // some error
                    },
                });
            };
    }

        //call ViewModel on document.ready
        $(function () {

            var searcher= new Searcher();
            searcher.Search();
            ko.applyBindings(searcher);

        });

//the page

    <div class="input-wrap">
                    <label for="type_short">
                        <b>Type:</b>
                    </label>
 <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: noneType" />
                    <span>Any</span>
                </label>
                    <!-- ko foreach: types -->
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data.id, checked: $root.selectedTypes, click: $root.Filter " />
                        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
                        <strong class="filter_result_count" data-bind="text: $data.count"></strong>
                    </label>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <div class="input-wrap">
                    <label for="rating">
                        <b>Rating:</b>
                    </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: noneRating" />
                    <span>Any</span>
                </label>
                    <!-- ko foreach: rating -->
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedRatings, click: $root.Filter " />
                        <span data-bind="text: $data + ' Stars'"></span>
                    </label>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
```

Some help would be appretiated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the

```
click: $root.Filter
```

binding. Instead, call `self.Filter` whenever `selectedRatings` changes by including

```
self.selectedRatings.subscribe(Filter);
```

at the end of your `Searcher` view model.

Comment: I make some changes, due to I need to have a checkbox that uncheck the checked ones, so i put a subscriptor to the selected ratings, See the updated code. Any help is appreciated

Comment: it didn't work for me this 'self.selectedRatings.subscribe(Filter);' when it changes don't call to filter... can you help me? thanks

Comment: Try `self.selectedRatings.subscribe(function() { debugger; self.Filter(); })` with your browser developer tools open. See whether it hits the breakpoint.

Comment: I try this and it worked with the features i told you in the changes:
`//Rating
        self.noneRating = ko.observable(true);

        self.selectedRatings.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            self.noneRating(newValue && newValue.length == 0 ? true : false);
            self.Filter();
        }, self);

        self.noneRating.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                self.selectedRatings.removeAll();
               self.Filter();
            }
            
        });`
**THANKS**